# A question about the cardinality of a set of functions with finite support where the domain of each function has cardinality aleph-null.

Tags: set-theory, order-theory

Suppose that $M$ is a well ordered set with at least two elements and that $L$ is a well ordered set with the same cardinality as the natural numbers. Let $[L, s.f, M]$ be the set of all functions $f:L\to M$ with finite support. Is there an injection from $L$ to $[L, s.f,M]$? The support of $f$ is the set of all $x\in L$ such that $f(x)\neq a$, where $a≤y$, for all $y\in M$. My thought is that for each $n$ of $L$, there is a function $f*:L\to M$ such that $f*(x)=y$, for all $x≤n$  (where $y$ is not the least element of $M$) and for all $x>n,f*(x)=a$ (where $a$ is the least element of $M$). Since for each such $n$, the support of $f*$ would have the cardinality $n$, namely a finite cardinality, it would follow that there is a countably infinite number of these functions from $L$ to $M$, and so, an injection from $L$ to $[L, s.f, M]$.  Am I missing something important?

Thanks.

Comment: Since your question is extremely notation heavy, write your question using LaTex.

Comment: Just learnt LaTex! Is this better?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, since $M$ is just a linearly ordered set, there is no reason why $M$ needs to have a least element. So you definition of support is not well-defined if $M$ does not have a least element. But let me assume that $M$ does have a least element $a$. Since $M$ has at least two elements, let $b$ be any other element of $M$.

For each $x \in L$, let $f_x : L \rightarrow M$ be defined by
$$f_x(u) = \begin{cases}
a & \quad u \neq x \\
b & \quad u = x
\end{cases}$$

It is clear that $f_x$ is a function with finite support. If $x \neq y$, then clealy $f_x \neq f_y$.

Define $\Phi$ by $\Phi(x) = f_x$. $\Phi$ is an injection of $L$ into the set of all functions from $L$ to $M$ with finite support.

Comment: Sorry, I meant to write "well ordered". Correction made.

Answer (score 1):

The following was edited to take into account that $M$ is not necessarily assumed countable. I use the symbol $0$ to refer to the "null" element of $M$, whose inverse image is the complement of the "support".

Let $M^L_n = \left \{ f \in M^L : \text{supp}(f) \text{ has cardinality } n \right \}$. There is a bijection from $L^n \times M^n$ to $M^L_n$ which is given by

$$f(l_1,\dots,l_n,m_1,\dots,m_n)(l) = \begin{cases}
m_i, & l = l_i \\
0, & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}$$

Intuitively this bijection chooses $n$ elements of $L$ to be the support of $f$, then independently chooses elements of $M$ to be the image of those points.

Now provided the axiom of choice, we have that, for $n>0$, $|L^n \times M^n| = \max \left \{ |M^n|,|L^n| \right \} = \max \{ |M|,|L| \}$. Both of these equalities require that $L$ is assumed to be infinite.

Finally, the set $M^L_f = \left \{ f \in M^L : \text{supp}(f) \text{ is finite} \right \}$ is exactly $\bigcup_{n=0}^\infty M^L_n$. This union is disjoint. Therefore $M^L_f$ has cardinality $\max \{ \aleph_0,|M|,|L| \} = \max \{ |M|,|L| \}$, again because $L$ is assumed to be infinite (and because $\aleph_0$ is the smallest transfinite cardinal).

Comment: Are you assuming $M$ is countable? I think the OP only said that $M$ has at least two elements but could possibly be uncountable.

Comment: Good point, I am assuming $M$ is countable; in fact, I am technically assuming that $M$ is countably infinite, although this isn't necessary for the argument. If we drop the assumption that $M$ is countable, my argument still says that $M^L_n$ has a natural bijection to $L^n \times M^n$. Provided the background set theory has "enough" choice (in particular, in ZFC), this has cardinality $\max \{ \aleph_0, |M| \}$, so the OP's set also has cardinality $\max \{ \aleph_0, |M| \}$.

Comment: I had not considered that $M$ could be uncountable. I also realized that $M$ need only be non-empty and well-ordered, since if $M$ was single membered, $supp(f)$ would be the empty set, and so, finite as well. I'm very new to this, so I haven't seen the triple bar between two sets before, but here it means the two sets are equivalent? Also, I don't follow the second argument, since I don't know what a natural bijection is. I'm assuming "enough choice" means the axiom of choice?

Comment: $|M|$ is the cardinality of $M$. "Natural bijection" is not a technical term in this context: the existence of a bijection to $L^n \times M^n$ follows "naturally" from what I said in words. More explicitly, for a given element of $L^n \times M^n$, call it $(l_1,\dots,l_n,m_1,\dots,m_n)$, we have a function $f$ whose support is $\{ l_1,\dots,l_n \}$ such that $f(l_i)=m_i$ for $i=1,\dots,n$. Finally, provided the axiom of choice, one can prove that for any two infinite cardinal numbers $\kappa,\ell$, $\kappa \cdot \ell = \max \{ \kappa,\ell \}$.

Comment: (Continued) Thus, that last part implies that $M^L_n$ has cardinality $\max \{ |L^n|,|M^n| \}$, which (since $L$ is countably infinite) is $\max \{ |L|,|M| \}$. Then taking countable unions doesn't change this (since $L$ is infinite), so $M^L$ also has cardinality $\max \{ |L|,|M| \}$. Note that if we assume both $L$ and $M$ are countable then the choice axiom required here is only the axiom of countable choice.

Comment: Oh, I didn't clarify the $\equiv$, it could just as well have been $=$. The point is just that the collection of functions of finite support can be decomposed into countably many pieces, one for each possible cardinality of the support.